# Can't run a linkage script through VIM

Tags: c++, bash, vim, g++, linkage

1. Hello, I wrote a bash script that compile several cpp's and object files 
   in g++. My goal is to run the script in vim by :!, but 
   it doesn't works within vim, only when I'm outside.
2. In addition I wanted to why using % in a script
   doesn't give me the current file, but gives an error
   instead.

the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Search for the main module and remove the ext.
delimain=`grep main *.cpp | cut -d. -f1`

# Checks if there are also object files
if [ -f ./*.o ]; then
g++ -g *.cpp *.o -o $delimain.exe
# If There are only cpp file
else
g++ -g *.cpp -o $delimain.exe
fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: That code seems to work fine for me (though I have to add -l to the grep command). Maybe use a GNU makefile instead?

Comment: It works to you fine inside vim?
Can you try to do this with alias?

Comment: Vim calls bash to call other program. So vim can also call bash to call the `make` program.

Comment: I wan't it to work without the "make" command..

Comment: What doesn't work? How? Is your script a real file in your $PATH? Is vim even able to see it?

Comment: I confirm that it works even inside vim ("!./build"), though I am using Linux and it looks like you are using Windows. Could you tell me what you mean by 'alias'?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 13.10
alias: alias link 'sh ~/bin/lin_script %'
I've also tried without the % (% = current file, am I right?)
It gives an error: "link: missing operand
Try 'link --help' for more information."

Answer (score 1):

RE your comment

> I'm using ubuntu 13.10 alias: alias link 'sh ~/bin/lin_script %'

1. You should not invoke a shell script with an explicit interpreter; the `#!/bin/bash` first line tells the shell already which interpreter to use. You're obviously a beginner in Bash; try to read some introductions to gain a better understanding.
2. Aliases **won't work in Vim** because they are only defined in an *interactive shell*, but the commands launched from Vim usually are launched in a non-interactive shell (because this is faster and comes with less unnecessary stuff).
3. The alias is interpreted by the *shell*, but the `%` symbol is special to Vim. The two are not the same. See my other answer how to pass a filename to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that `%` is automatically expanded **when supplied to an Ex command inside Vim**, but this does not apply to external scripts. What you have to do is pass the current file when invoking the external script, and in there reference the command-line argument:

Inside Vim:

```
:!linkage.sh %
```

In your script:

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    delimain=$1
else
    delimain=`grep ...
```

Comment: I think I've located the problem,
It doesn't work in alias.. 
only when giving the script current location...
Why is that?

Comment: Can you please explain about .sh?
My script doesn't contains that ext.

Comment: File extensions are not important; it's the `#!/bin/bash` line that matters. This was just an example.